# What causes this cloud formation?

Tags: clouds

This was taken about November 18 in southern Arizona, USA. I’ve never seen any clouds like this before. Is it natural or caused by some airplane?

[image]

Comment: looks like kelvin helmholtz wave. This kind of cloud has been identified on this site. You need to check. I canot answer at the moment because i am using a mobile device to commuinicate

Comment: Here you go - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kelvin%E2%80%93Helmholtz_instability#/media/File:Wavecloudsduval.jpg and read this great answer - https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/10004/what-might-cause-these-wave-clouds-near-the-horizon-could-it-be-gravity-waves/15801#15801

Comment: Thank you! I appreciate it.